# Extract latest incoming email message body from an reply email

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime-message

We have created a method for extracting incoming email attachments while reading the incoming emails from the s3 storage and we are using  JavaMail API of version 1.6.2 for it. We need to get the latest message from the email without the previous correspondence. Currently, we are using MimeMessageParser to extract the incoming email data. How do we get only the new response text? We are using java version 1.6 and spring version 4.1.4.RELEASE. I have done so many searches but failed. If anybody knows a good standard way please help me.